# How to store thousands of data store in Sqlite at runtime in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I got approx 50,000 Json data in response after successful login. I have to parse this data and store in Sqlite database without stopping the ui(means user can move to main activity and data should store in background). I use following code:

```
new Thread(){
   getDataFromServer();
}).start;

public void getDataFromServer(){
   storeDataInDb(List<Object> jsonResponseList);
}

public void storeDataInDb(List<Object> jsonResponseList){
   db.beginTransaction();
 try {
   ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
   cv.put("name","name");
   .....//5 columns
   db.insert("tableName", null, cv);
   db.setTransactionSuccessful();
 }catch {
    
 }finally {
    db.endTransaction();
 }
}
```

By this above coding data is storing in background but sometimes it is failing.
Could someone explain better approach for this scenario. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use Android `Service`

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend to using kotlin use coroutines because its easy to learn and implement, but for java user you can use rxjava [enter link description here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) or AsyncTask [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

Comment: I can't use AsyncTask here because this stops the user in the same activity. In my case user can move into another activity between these saving happening.

Answer (score 0):

use Asyntask , the UI will run separable from the sqlite code

Comment: This stops the user in same layout. In my case user is moving into another activity without any delay.